# PHP Check JSON to see if it is pending and/or not pending

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON string.

- I want to echo "pending" if the status is pending,
- I want to echo "Active" if the status is active, and
- I want to echo "Invalid" if invalid.

**Json**

Pending:

```
"{"result":"success","message":"License key details retrieved.","status":"pending","max_allowed_domains":"1","email":"","registered_domains":[],"date_created":"","date_renewed":"","date_expiry":""}"
```

Active:

```
"{"result":"success","message":"License key details retrieved.","status":"active","max_allowed_domains":"1","email":"","registered_domains":[],"date_created":"","date_renewed":"","date_expiry":""}"
```

Invalid:

```
"{"result":"error","message":"Invalid license key"}"
```

Thank you!

Comment: so decode the json into a native php structure, and then you access/test members of that structure like you would any other structure.

Comment: And what have you tired? We help solve issue not give you answers...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, start by using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on your variable that contains the JSON string.

After that, you should be able to check the values in your array.

A loose example:

```
$arr = json_decode($json_string);

if($arr['result'] == "error"){
    echo "Invalid";
}elseif($arr['result'] == "success" && $arr['status'] == "pending"){
    echo "Pending";
}elseif($arr['result'] == "success" && $arr['status'] == "active"){
    echo "Active";
}else{
    echo "what if it's something else??";
}
```